# How to make a custom list adapter with textbox and imageview from web?

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, android-imageview, listadapter

I'm using a parameterized Uri link that I ran through AsyncTask to acquire(GET) some info whenever the user gives some info in a TextBox and hits the Button to start the task.

I get the response and insert that info as JSONObject and put it into an ArrayList of HashMap that consists three fields, fullname, username and the PhotoByte.

What I want is to make a custom adapter for the ListView in order to display that info. I know how to decodeByteArray to a Bitmap and set it to an ImageView but somewhere I'm struggling.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) on how to make a custom adapter which is Ok...but I don't need to instantiate HttpConnections neither I need to load image from url, instead I need to convert byteArray given from the url and show it in the ImageView within the ListView item of that custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an .xml file, something like row.xml in which you set your TextViews and ImageViews (and Buttons) as you like it.

You also need to build the custom adapter just like shown in the link here:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

I found this to be one of the best and easiest custom listadapter tutorials around.

Also, worth mentioning, some optimization is recommended since chances are the listview will be quite slow and not-snappy on less powerful devices.

Comment: Already have created a custom listview XML layout so I can inflate it and yeah you're right on optimization. I'm checking the link you provided and give my feedback about your answer soon.

Comment: That tutorial is pretty much sophisticated as I ran and scan through but doesn't give me the answer because I have the problem to parse the ByteArray in that adapter and then handle it by decoding into Bitmap and than set the ImageView setBitmap to that newly created Bitmap image.

Answer (score 0):

yes use a custom adapter, inside it you can do whatever you like ;) Here is some code, but you should maybe look at other examples to figure out how an adapter works.

```
>      public class Adapter_Custom extends BaseAdapter {
>         
>           // DEBUG
>           private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
>         
>           // Layout
>           private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
>           public ViewHolder holder;
>           View vi;
>         
>           Context context;
>           private ArrayList<Item_Pin> pinItems;
>         
>           public Adapter_Custom(Context context, ArrayList<Item_Pin> pinItems) {
>               this.context    = context;
>               this.pinItems   = pinItems;
>               
>               inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>           }
>         
>           // Used internally by this class
>           public int getCount() {
>               return pinItems.size();
>           }
>           
>           // 
>           @Override
>           public long getItemId(int position) {
>               // Return whatever u like here
>               return 0;
>           }
>         
>           @Override
>           public String getItem(int position) {
>               return "You can return whatever u like here";
>           }
>         
>           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>         
>               vi = convertView;
>          // If there is no ViewHolder already, create a new one
>               if(convertView  ==  null){
>                   vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_file, null);
>                   holder = new ViewHolder();
>         
>                   holder.title        = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.your_xml_file_textview);
>                   holder.background   = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.your_xml_file_linearlayout);
>         
>                   vi.setTag(holder);
>                   holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag(); // If there already is a viewholder, reuse it!                 
} else {
>                   holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
>               }
>          // This is where you place code for every list item - this is where you convert your base64 to images.
>               holder.title.setText(pinItems.get(position).getPinText());
>               // here you could also set the background of holder.background to your base64 image.
>         
>               return vi;
>           }
>         
>           //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>           // VIEWHOLDER - This is the code part of your XML
>           //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>           public class ViewHolder{
>         
>               public TextView title;
>               public LinearLayout background;
>         
>           }
>         }
```

Use that code and replace it with your own XML file and data, then simply put code in the getView() method that converts your byte arrays to images for every list item.